# I have problems with compiling powertop on Ubuntu Precise

Tags: 12.04, make, powertop, compiling

I tried to compile the latest release of powertop from github.

I get [some errors](http://pastebin.com/7wwhfqWT) and I dont know what to do to fix this.

```
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/powertop/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/powertop/src'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/powertop/po'
test ! -f ./powertop.pot || \
      test -z "hu_HU.gmo id_ID.gmo zh_TW.gmo" || make hu_HU.gmo id_ID.gmo zh_TW.gmo
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/powertop/po'
rm -f hu_HU.gmo && : -c --statistics --verbose -o hu_HU.gmo hu_HU.po
mv: cannot stat `t-hu_HU.gmo': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [hu_HU.gmo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/powertop/po'
make[2]: *** [stamp-po] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/powertop/po'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/powertop'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following

```
 sudo apt-get install gettext 
 make clean
./configure 
 make
```

Comment: whole log: http://pastebin.com/RnvhQ9ve